# Sheets ArrayFormula. Find nearest number by group

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

### Master Data

Group-Value pairs

```
1 |  1
1 |  2
1 |  3
2 |  5
2 |  8
3 | 10
3 | 12
```

### Work Data

Group-Value pairs + desired result

```
1 | 4 | 3 (3≤4, max in group 1)
1 | 2 | 2 (2≤2, max in group 1)
2 | 6 | 5 (5≤6, max in group 2)
3 | 7 | no result (both 10 and 12 > than 7)
```

---

The task is to find the maximum possible matched number from a group, the number should be less or equal to the given number.

For `Group 1, value 4`:

`=> filter Master Data (1,2,3) => find 3`

Will have no problem with doing it once, need to do it with arrayformula.

My attempts to solve it were using modifications of the `vlookup` formula, with wrong outputs so far.

Samples and my working "arena":

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Cd2BGpGN-0h2bL0LQ_EpIDBKKT2hvTVHoxGC6i8uTE/edit?usp=sharing

Notes: no need to solve it in a single formula, because it may slow down the result.

Comment: There is a naive solution along the lines of =ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(D4:D8&text(E4:E8,"0000"),A4:A10&text(B4:B10,"0000"),1,true)) then check for correct group but I'm sure there is something more elegant.

Comment: @tom-sharpe, thanks, I've missed it, may work. Could you give it as an answer, please? Please note groups may have same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(D4:D8&text(E4:E8,"0000"),A4:A10&text(B4:B10,"0000"),1,true))
```

starting in J4

then

```
=ArrayFormula(if(--left(J4:J8)=D4:D8,--right(J4:J8,4),""))
```

starting in K4.

[image]

Needs further refinement but doesn't make any assumptions about max of previous group.

**EDIT**

So after further work it would look like this

```
=ArrayFormula(if(D4:D="",,
if(D4:D=
vlookup(D4:D&text(E4:E,"0000"),filter({A4:A&text(B4:B,"0000"),A4:A},A4:A<>""),2,true),
vlookup(D4:D&text(E4:E,"0000"),filter({A4:A&text(B4:B,"0000"),B4:B},A4:A<>""),2,true),"")))
```

A lot like @player0's solution in fact.

I guess you could make it a bit more general by doing something like

```
=text(B4,rept("0",ceiling(log10(max(B4:B)))))
```

assuming these are positive integers.

---

**Alternative method**

I think this is a better way. Find the start row of each group and how many rows r less than or equal to the required group/value pair are in that group. Then just go forward r-1 rows from the first line of the group to find the matching value:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(countifs(A4:A,D4:D,B4:B,"<="&E4:E)>0,
vlookup(
  vlookup(D4:D,{A4:A,row(A4:A)},2,false)+countifs(A4:A,D4:D,B4:B,"<="&E4:E)-1,{row(A4:A),B4:B},2,false),))
```

Assuming of course that the Master data is sorted by group and value - otherwise you would have to use sort():

```
=ArrayFormula(if(countifs(A4:A,D4:D,B4:B,"<="&E4:E)>0,
vlookup(
  vlookup(D4:D,{sort(A4:A,A4:A,1,B4:B,1),row(A4:A)},2,false)+countifs(A4:A,D4:D,B4:B,"<="&E4:E)-1,{row(A4:A),SORT(B4:B,A4:A,1,B4:B,1)},2,false),))
```

[image]

Comment: I think I've found a better way - plz see Alternative method.

Comment: Super! Thanks for your efforts, Tom! I think you should mention you assumed the Master data was sorted.

Comment: Agreed! Will add it it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was based on the technique of finding the maximum number by a row. The sample formula is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=628408999

My whole solution is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Cd2BGpGN-0h2bL0LQ_EpIDBKKT2hvTVHoxGC6i8uTE/edit#gid=0

### Step 1

Get joined numbers by groups from a Master Table.

```
1 | 3,2,1
2 | 8,5
3 | 12,10
```

Used `offset` to achieve this ↑. And used `vlookup` to match this semi-result with work table.

### Step 2

Used `if` + `split` to check if the resulted value was ≤ than my work value, and in the same formula used query to find the maximum by each row.

compose a query: used `join` + `sequence`

`=IF(M3=0,,"select "&JOIN(", ",INDEX("max(Col"&SEQUENCE(M3)&")")))`

result:

`select max(Col1), max(Col2), max(Col3), max(Col4), max(Col5)`

Found the maximum by each group:

`=index(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(data), "select ...")))`

This final formula was the  to solving the problem.

Note: the result: 0 of my formula means "no matches". This is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(IF(E4:E>=
 VLOOKUP(D4:D&TEXT(E4:E, "00000"), {A4:A&TEXT(FILTER(B4:B, B4:B<>""), "00000"), B4:B}, 2), 
 VLOOKUP(D4:D&TEXT(E4:E, "00000"), {A4:A&TEXT(FILTER(B4:B, B4:B<>""), "00000"), B4:B}, 2), 0)))
```

[image]